# How is text thickness calculated according to css property "font-weight"?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Font weight in Firefox:

[image: font-weight in firefox]

Font weight in Chrome:

[image: font-weight in chrome]

The `font-weight` value is in the order of 100,500,600,700,900, which is set according to the W3C standard.

You can clearly see that the text thickness is not changed linearly, and in different browser not exactly the same (it's almost the same from 100 to 500.). So I wonder, is there a standard on how the text is calculated according to `font-weight`?

Comment: Actually, 400 is normal, and 700 is bold. Those are the only numeric values that most text rendering engines support. It is mostly not the browser that is the problem.

Comment: @BoltClock That was `400` and `700`. However, it's not a restriction in the browsers, but in how the fonts are defined. Most have only two thicknesses.

Comment: Yeah the part about browsers was my mistake. Oops.

Comment: This is actually a bug report for WebKit in disguise: why does it screw up font rendering at a weight of 600 when the font does not have such a width available?

Comment: @ThemeZ The middle line in the second picture shows the regular weight font "bolded" by the browser, i.e. each letter is doubled. The lower two lines are the real bold font.

Comment: @CodyGray I seem to remember that older versions of Firefox (or maybe it was the Mozilla Suite) did the same for font weight=600. That way, it simulated more weights than just the two. It looks a lot better with large font sizes though.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but speaking of widths and WebKit, here is something I recently discovered:  If you have three inline-block elements and set the width of each to 33.33% in CSS, there is a gap of about with 3 pixels (assuming a wrapper div).  This is because WebKit, when faced with a pixel fraction, always `floors`, so if the wrapper div is 45px, 33.33% would be 14.85. The width for each inner div is floored to 14, making the total inner widths 42, leaving that 3 pixel gap. So I can imagine that if the font-weight gives a pixel fraction for each glyph, similar wackiness ensues.

Comment: Thank you guys, now I know how to handle this problem.

Comment: I would say that `font-hinting` has a lot to do with this. Also if it is a PC or a MAC and what type you are using.
Probably, there's `font-hinting` only for `400` and `700` and it's not cross-plataform / cross-browser. [This is a good article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/02/the-ails-of-typographic-anti-aliasing/) about this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm, at least in theory, is: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight

The CSS3 specification is similar - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop

As it states, bold faces are often synthesized by user agents for faces that lack actual bold faces.

I've found its often better to avoid font-weights all together, and use a specific font face.

Comment: you're right, people rarely use numeric values, insteadly use specific font faces. So most browser donot support that, but what I don't understand is that they don't even implement _bolder_ and _lighter_